# Logical truth and logical consequence

Tags: first-order-logic

I understand the concept of logical consequence, for example:

1.All persons are human

2.I am a person

Conclusion: I am human.

If 1 and 2 are true, conclusion must be true.

My question is about `logical truth`

would this be a logical truth for example?

1. My name is Drx
2. Drx is batman

conclusion: 100 = 100

As I understand it the conclusion is true no matter what the premises are. But my definition says:

> A logical truth is a sentence that is a logical consequence of any set
>   of premises. That is, no matter what the premises may be, it is
>   impossible for the conclusion to be false.

Is the conclusion above really a logical consequence of its premises even when the premise doesnt have anything to do with the conclusion?

Sorry if this got confusing, if the above is not a logical truth please give me an easy example :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [logical truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-truth/) today we mean a *valid* formula, i.e. a formula that is true in every *interpretation*.

In *propositional logic*, a valid formula is called: *tautology*.

Examples:

> $A \to (B \to A) \ , \ A \lor \lnot A$, etc.

Tautologies can be identified via [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) algorithm.

In general, the link between *logical consequence* and "logical truth" is the following:

> if the formula $C$ is *logical consequence* of the formulae $A$ and $B$, i.e.
>
> > $A, B \vDash C$,
>
> then $(A \land B) \to C$ is *valid*.

---

With your example:

> 1.All persons are human
>
> 2.I am a person
>
> Conclusion: I am human

we have that: "If all persons are human and I am a person, then I am human" is a *logical truth*.

---

The formula $x=x$ is a (first-order) axiom for equality and thus is *valid*.

Every instance of it, like e.g. $100=100$ and "Socrates=Socrates" is a *logical truth*.